# Unable to Connect my server within my local network

Tags: oracle10g, localhost, portforwarding

I have created a account at `no-ip.com` to access my oracle server from out side. when i'm trying to access my server within my local network using my `no-ip url`, it's not worked. got error message:

> can't establish a connection to the server at 112.125.117.25:8080.

what is the matter?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem as well. My guess is it has something to do with NAT - because once I changed my router the problem went away. You could definitely solve the problem by referring to your server by its internal name when within the same network.